# Save object only if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add an easy condition on saving an object, but can't find where I should put it.

I have a space and a booking model. My space has a "minimum_days" column. What I want is that if the number of days of the booking is smaller  than the minimum_days of the space, the booking won't be saved and the form will be rendered again with errors.

For that, I have a very simple condition in my bookings controller : 
`if @booking.space.minimum_days > number_of_days`

But I don't know what to do with it.

I've tried to put a "redirect_to" with a flash alert if the condition is met, but that does not work properly

I've also tried to add a "validate" in my model and create a method:

```
validates :must_respect_minimum_days

def must_respect_minimum_days
    if @booking.booking_type == "daily"
      number_of_days = @booking.end_time.to_date - @booking.start_time.to_date).to_i
      if @booking.space.minimum_days > number_of_days
        errors.add(:minimum_days, "You did not book enough days")
      end
    end
  end
```

But it says @booking is nil.... I've also tried to replace @booking with my params, but I can't access the params in the model method. It tells me `` undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Booking:0x00007f8ec2b57e00> ``

What is the easiest way to do that ? That sounds easy but for some reason I can't make it work!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code you posted is located in the booking model, the object you should refer to is 'self'.

```
self.booking_type == "daily"
```

Or

```
booking_type == "daily"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was actually an easy one!! Cheers